# How to display json data with Angular-highcharts?

Tags: json, angular, highcharts

I am working an angular + node dashboard application and having trouble displaying JSON data in highcharts

JSON response:
`[{"output":"FAIL","count":"4"},{"output":"PASS","count":"17"}]`

```js
public uat_deployment_chart_options: Highcharts.Options;

//this is the method I created to fetch the data
public get_uat_deployment_data() {
    this.uat_deployment_subscription = this.curl_connection
      .get_uat_deployment_data()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.uat_deployment_data = data;

        this.uat_deployment_data.forEach(val => {
          val.count = parseInt(val.count)
        });

        this.uat_deployment_chart_options = {
          title: {
            text: "UAT Deployments"
          },
          series: [
            {
              data: this.uat_deployment_data,
              type: "pie",
              colors: ["#F44336", "#CDDC39"]
            }
          ],
          credits: {
            enabled: false
          },
        };
      });
  }
```

If I manually paste the data and change the object keys to, "name" and "y" respectively the data is displayed, otherwise I get nothing

`[{ "name": "FAIL", "y": 3 }, { "name": "PASS", "y": 16 }]`

Comment: So you just need to write and call a function that transforms the array of objects `[{"output":"FAIL","count":"4"},{"output":"PASS","count":"17"}]` into the array of objects `[{ "name": "FAIL", "y": 4 }, { "name": "PASS", "y": 17 }]`. That really shouldn't be too hard. Have you tried doing it?

Comment: No I haven't tried that JB, I will do so now

Comment: Hi JB, so I did what you suggested and it worked ```        this.uat_deployment_data = this.uat_deployment_data.map(item => {
          return {
            name: item.output,
            y: item.count
          };
        });```  but I have to graph...